# Android: Detecting user tampering with phone

Tags: android, button, hardware, tampering

I'd like to detect when a user presses any hardware button on a sleeping android phone (or at least the home and the power button).

Until now I have used a BroadcastReceiver for the ACTION_SCREEN_ON event, which works great but it is also raised when e.g. you get a message, a phone call or when an alarm starts.

ACTION_USER_PRESENT is also no option because this is only raised when the user really is present an knows the unlock code, so he isn't tampering with the phone.

Is there a way to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

no its not possible 
but this can be used for other purpose

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) 
    {



    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So is there no possibility at all to detect from a service whether a user is present or not?